# MySQL join with two conditions

Tags: mysql, performance, join, left-join

With a single query, I need to get a list of ALL objects A and an additional column returning "1" when there is an association to an Object C in Table B, or returning "0" when there is no associaton to an Object C in Table B.

Table A holds all objects A
Table B holds all objects A associated to another object C.

I know the ID of object C.

Currently I am using a Query with LEFT JOIN and two conditions with AND in the JOIN.
For the return value column I am using "(TableB.id IS NOT NULL) as associated".

Table A will likely hold only between dozens up to a hundred records.
Table B will likely hold between thousands to hundreds of thousands records.
Table C will likely hold between thousands to hundreds of thousands records.

```
TableA.id is index
TableB.tablea_id is index
TableB.id is index
TableB.tablec_id is index
TableC.id is index
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT TableA.name, TableA.code, (TableB.id IS NOT NULL) AS associated
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.id=TableB.tablea_id AND TableB.tablec_id = $input
```

Is there any performance concern about the method I use for the SQL query or a better way of achieving the desired result ?

Comment: Your query is just fine. I don't think there's a better way.  For portability with non-MySQL, you would need to use a `CASE` as in `CASE WHEN TableB.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS associated` , but the way you have it `(TABLEB.id IS NOT NULL)` is fine and the most concise for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine as far as I can see.

However, you should keep in mind that **conditions on `join` should be for matching foreign keys**. Following this practice at least makes your queries more readable and maintainable.